# *-homomorphism and *-representation

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

I understand the concept of the unitary representation of G
. A unitary representation of G is group homomorphism π:G→U(H) where H is a complex Hilbert space and U(H) is the group of unitary operators on H.

I am reading the "A course in abstract harmonic analysis" of Folland . But I do not know the definitions of *-homomorphism and *-representations.
Please help me!

Comment: Star-algebras are just algebras with an involution denoted by an asterisk.  [Here's a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-algebra).

Comment: @ SpamIAm 1  :Can you please describe *-representation with its properties?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm grossly underqualified to provide an answer! $*$-homomorphism is defined in the Wiki article.  If we're just considering complex representations, a star-representation of a $*$-algebra $A$ is just a $*$-homomorphism $A \to M_n(\mathbb{C})$, the set of complex $n \times n$ matrices.  More generally, you can instead take the codomain to be $End_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ for $V$ a finite-dimensional complex vector space.  N.B. The $*$ on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the conjugate transpose.